# How to Subscribe to GUI Events in Other JFrames

Tags: java, events, subscribe

What is the best practice for subscribing to events from another JFrame?  For example, I have a "settings" form, and when the user presses okay on the settings form, I want the main form to know about this so it can retrieve the settings.

Thanks.

Here is my ideal interface:

```
public void showSettingsButton_Click() {
   frmSettings sForm = new sForm(this._currentSettings);
   //sForm.btnOkay.Click = okayButtonClicked;   // What to do here?
   sForm.setVisible(true);
}

public void okayButtonClicked(frmSettings sForm) {
    this._currentSettings = sForm.getSettings();
}
```

Comment: *"What is the best practice for subscribing to events from another form?"*  Do you mean a `JFrame`?  Please note that I don't speak 'yourIDE'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry. In C# they are called forms.  Not really familiar with the Java terminology yet.

Comment: A-Ha!  Netbeans also coaxes developers into referring to `JFrames` as 'forms', as well.  Thanks for editing the question.

Answer (score 2):

Someone publishes an Event, that something has changed, here the settings. A subscriber that registered for this specifig event, gets notified about it and can do his work, here get the settings. This is called publisher/subscriber.

For this you can use [Eventbus](http://www.eventbus.org) or implementing something smaller on your own.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to have only a single `JFrame`.  All the other 'free floating top level containers' could be modal dialogs.  Access the the main GUI will be blocked until the current dialog is dismissed, and the code in the main frame can check the settings of the dialog after it is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here is what I ended up going with.  I'm not sure if it's the best way, but it is working for my purposes.

```
// Method called when the "Show Settings" button is pressed from the main JFrame
private void showSettingsButton_Click() {

   // Create new settings form and populate with my settings
   frmSettings sForm = new frmSettings(this.mySettings);

   // Get the "Save" button and register for its click event...
   JButton btnSave = sForm.getSaveButton();
   btnSave.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
                SaveSettings(sForm);
            }
   });

   // Show the settings form
   sForm.setVisible(true);
}

// Method called whenever the save button is clicked on the settings form
private void SaveSettings(frmSettings sForm) {
   // Get the new settings and assign them to the local member
   Settings newSettings = sForm.getSettings();
   this.mySettings = newSettings;
}
```

And if, like me, you are coming from a .NET perspective, here is the C# version:

```
private void showSettingsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   frmSettings sForm = new frmSettings(this.mySettings);
   sForm.btnSave += new EventHandler(SaveSettings);
   sForm.Show();
}

private void SaveSettings(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   frmSettings sForm = (frmSettings)sender;  // This isn't the exact cast you need..
   Settings newSettings = sForm.Settings;
   this.mySettings = newSettings;
}
```